# Can't find SecurityMockMvcConfigurers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I'am trying to write a spring security test as described here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-setup. I need to import `SecurityMockMvcConfigurers` as a static import, but my IDE does not find the class.

My pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.M2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Spring Boot 1.4.0.M2 imports Spring Security 4.0.4.RELEASE. I' can't find the class in this release. Which additional dependency do I need? Or what else I haven't considered?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The missing dependency was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This should be declared in your Maven `pom.xml` file

Comment: For copy-pasters: remember to add the scope test.

Comment: Unable to find out where to add this code. I tried in root-context and servlet-context, both gave errors ` Line 31 in XML document from URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid;`

Comment: it is a prerequisite that your project is set up as a maven project. Then add this code in the dependencies section of your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 4):

The required dependency for the `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers` class is the `org.springframework.security:spring-security-test` dependency.

The question is tagged Spring Boot and Spring Boot provides the dependency as a managed dependency in the `spring-boot-starter-parent` pom.
Your pom inherits very probably from `spring-boot-starter-parent`.
So above all don't specify a version without a very good reason and use simply the version inherited from the parent.
That is enough :

```
<dependencies> 
     ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>         
    </dependency>
     ...
<dependencies>
```

For example with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5, the managed version is

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
  </dependency>
```

The `M5` is not just chance.
These are designed to work "better" together.

Note that `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test` dependency doesn't pull the `spring-security-test` dependency.

In case you don't use Spring Boot, you should endeavor to specify a `spring-security-test` version conform to the Core Spring version used by the application.

Answer (score -2):

The class SecurityMockMvcConfigurers is included in

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In other releases SecurityMockMvcConfigurers may not exist.

However there is a class MockMvcConfigurer, may be you can work with this instead ?

**regarding : but this dependency does not contain the corresponding class.**

Yes you are right that class is not inluded in the jar.
So I think you have to use what is there.
Anyway, the class is rather simple and the sourcecode is here :
[SecurityMockMvcConfigurers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/test/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/test/web/servlet/setup/SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.java)

Just copy the code in your own class and you are done.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this dependency does not contain the corresponding class.